# why pressing a button a php form the table displayed disappear?

Tags: php

I have a form with a list box which report some id client recorded in a MySql database. I select one of this id client I click on a button - named `selected-record`, I get data from the db and these are displayed on a php table. This is fine. Then I click on a second button called `delete-record` with the goal to get the id of the client - variable `$num_client` - and to run the sql delete instruction to delete the record. 2 points I was not able so far to fix.

1. Why pressing "delete_record" button the table displayed pressind `selected_record` is immediately cancelled on a form?
2. Why when I press `delete_record` the instruction `echo`num_client;` gives an empty value?

```
if ( isset($_POST['selected_record'])){
        // visualiazzazione tabella
```

`` echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Id cliente</th>
        <th>Ragione Sociale</th>
        <th>address</th>
        <th>village</th>
        <th>Provincia</th>
        <th>Contatto</th>
        <th>Dipartimento</th>
    </tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $num_client. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rag_soc. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $address. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $village. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $provincia. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $contact_client. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $dipart. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    echo "</table>";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id_cliente , ragione_sociale FROM clienti");
}

if( isset($_POST['delete_record'])) { 

// Here If I make echo $num_client this gives no value ??
//$sql_del = "DELETE FROM `db_ordini_clienti`.`clienti` WHERE `id_cliente` = $num_client";

} ``

Comment: when you click on `selected-record` button, your data will be `posted` to the server, your `php` code will retrieve proper data from the server and generates a `html` output to the clients browser. then after that with you click on `delete-record` button, this time some new data is being `posted` to the server. so your `php` code those not have access to any of the `variables` generated previous time. so you have to fill the `$num_client` variable first with proper data and then try to delete the record.

Comment: hello Nikolaidis, thanks for your answer. Regarding managing table is it correct to create table in php considering that when I press another key the table disappeared?.Or it's better to build the table with html and then populate it with php code ? I tried this last case but it's seems more difficult populate html table from php code.Thanks again